# Find values in mongodb with array

Tags: python, mongodb, find

I am trying to get values from a mongodb table which stores data about stock taking dates in a shop(the date is stored as string) along with python.

the data stored in the table:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5645f0443f32df13e0dc786e"),
    "RequiredDate" : "28-9-2015",
    "Name": "xyz"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5645f0c73f32df062064a0f6"),
    "RequiredDate" : "29-9-2015",
    "Name": "abc"
}
```

I would like to find the name of the products which are required on both days `28-9-2015 & 29-9-2015`.

Right now do it individually like this

```
db.stockdate.find({"RequiredDate": "28-9-2015"})
db.stockdate.find({"RequiredDate": "29-9-2015"})
```

Can i do these in a single query, Is there any option for that?
like giving both date in a single query and get the same result which i got with two query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

```
db.stockdate.find({"RequiredDate": {$in: ["28-9-2015", "29-9-2015"]}})
```

Additionally, if you'd just like the names of the products, you can use

```
db.stockdate.distinct("Name", {"RequiredDate": {$in: ["28-9-2015", "29-9-2015"]}})
```

If you want to group the records based on the dates, you will need to use aggregation:

```
db.stockdate.aggregate([
    {$match: {"RequiredDate": {$in: ["28-9-2015", "29-9-2015"]}}},
    {$group: {_id: "RequiredDate", Names: {$push: "$Name"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

The above aggregation query will produce a result like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "28-9-2015",
    "Names": ["xyz"],
    "count": 1
}
{
    "_id" : "29-9-2015",
    "Names": ["abc", "def"],
    "count": 2
}
```

You can add as many dates to the array, and this will return records that have the reuiredDate set to any of those dates.

Comment: There might me multiple results for the above query with(multiple dates) is there a way to know which date has stock taking so that i can give a total count of all the products that they are stock taking?

Comment: Okay. For that you will need to use aggregation. Gimme a minute for that.